# Min3d and Andar

Tags: android, augmented-reality, andar

I would like to load a model using Min3d and Andar but since i am new to Android and Java i am asking you if you have an example or something how to do this. I searched all over the internet and didn't found nothing.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

What i personally believe is that if one is targeting Android, one can use [FLARToolkit](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/saqoosha/FLARToolKit/en). It's written using Adobe Flex. Flex applications can be run on Android's AIR. If you are particular about using Java only, try [NyARToolkit](http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wiki/index.php?FrontPage.en)